# How to save # color in database in ASP.Net core

Tags: database, asp.net-core, addition, color-picker, farbtastic

I want to save # color to Data Base.

but it just 0 for FontAwesomeColor in data base:

My view model:

```
      public long FontAwesomeColor { get; set; }
```

part of my service:

```
        Service service = new Service()
        {
       .....
            FontAwesomeColor = createServiceViewModel.FontAwesomeColor

        };
```

but after add in data base , all details add to data base , except FontAwesomeColor

controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> CreateService(CreateServiceViewModel createServiceViewModel)
    {
        _siteService.CreateService(createServiceViewModel);

          

        return View(createServiceViewModel);
```

this is part of my view: ( I use from farbtastic for color Picker)

```
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ">
                            <div class="">
                                <label for="color" class=" " asp-for="FontAwesomeColor"></label>               

                                <input asp-for="FontAwesomeColor" type="submit" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" />

                                <div id="picker"></div>
                                <span asp-validation-for="FontAwesomeColor"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a long datatype for FontAwesomeColor? make it string

Comment: In your view model, does it have a non-zero value? In other words, is the problem in saving in the database, or in reading the input value? Note that "#123456" is an invalid `long` value because of that `#` and because of the hex digits

Comment: @Nahid first question:if i save it as string, how can i save as number in database? #123456 is for farbtastic setting and i didnot change it, How can I save this number without # in databse?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing 123456 is for farbtastic setting and i didnot change it, How can I save this number without # in databse?

Comment: If # is always upfront in number. Then you can split it in viewmodel when saving it. Same goes when getting it. Just add it upfront.

Comment: @nahid it is upfront, but i want to add just the number in dab, i dont know why it add just 0, when I set long. 2 question : if i change it to string in model , how can i change it to int? with converto , i cannot.

Comment: `int.Parse("123456", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)` = 1193046, but why do you insist on int/long instead of string?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing , because it is a number. I had inside string then convert it? is it better?

Comment: Usually, when you use it, you need to convert it back into a hex string anyway (PS `1193046.ToString("X6")` = 123456, or `$"#{1193046:X6}"` = #123456), so keeping it as string saves two conversions. But it's your choice as I don't know your exact usecase

Comment: @HansKeﬆing if i save it as string, I should convert it again to int? becasue its a number .yes? if yes , how can i write in service?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing it does not matter , it is hex, because i want just save a number in data base , that number i get it with color picker(farbtastic ) and then I want insert and save it in database to use it on the other place. now which way is better for this?

Comment: From that color picker you get a *string* value consisting of hex digits (with # prefix, apparently), not an integer. When you want to use that value to color some element, you usually also have to provide that color as a hex *string* (again, with # prefix), not an integer. Yes it represents an integer value, so you may save some storage bytes by converting to/from an int. Whatever is "best" is up to you - what kind of values work best *for you*?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing before last comment , i review it and its my result, yes its better it must be string, I understanding now. by the way now i had to save it on db. so should I convert it to some thing? ( or not ? because its string and need to save in db as string , right? )  in this way it save NULL. and doesn't accept from entrance, see the picture on question update

Comment: You will have to debug your app. Why is that value null? Investigate the whole chain, starting with "is that input really filled by your colorpicker", then "why don't I get that value back"? It is possible that the "asp-for" interferes with your "name=" attribute - I haven't tested

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thank you so much , it was because of  name="color", I delete it from view and it fet its value and save in Data base. but would you please why "name" was this happen?  and in data base it saved : #562212

Comment: `asp-for` sets up databinding, but needs to post that value back to FontAwesomeColor. Here the `name` attribute is used to get the value into the correct property. So you cannot change it

Comment: @HansKeﬆing but when I delete the name , it saved to data base. it means , you say , I should not delete [  name="color" ] from view?

Comment: do you have any progress? @masoudmazloum

Comment: @TinyWang Thank you so so much , now it s ok, but would you please explain it why i should delete name="color" , I cannot understand its relation.

Comment: thaks for your response! because `asp-for="FontAwesomeColor"` will add `name="FontAwesomeColor" id="FontAwesomeColor"` attribute for the `input`. Then the id is conflict, make the model binding failure. then you got null. @masoudmazloum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `string` instead of `long` for `FontAwesomeColor`. By the way, could you pls try to remove `id="color" name="color"` in your View and check if it's still `null`?

I copied your view and add the form so that I can submit it. By the way, I created the `ViewModel` which contained the model having `FontAwesomeColor`, then I got the null value as well.

[image]

After removing that part, it worked for me, that's because the model binding didn't work when the id is conflict.

[image]